# Past perfect when talking about the same day

Tags: past-perfect

I've tried asking a similar question and I still can't say that I understand this concept of past perfect. If you are talking about events that took place on the same day in chronological order, why do you still need to use past perfect? Please see my sentence below, which I think is fine.

> She was talking to her supervisor when I got to work this morning. Then as I was leaving, I saw her talking to her supervisor again. Something must be going on.

Also, even when I'm talking about yesterday and today, why do I need to use past perfect if I'm talking about them in chronological order?

> She emailed me yesterday to tell me that she was going to visit me next week. Then she emailed me again this morning and told me that she can't come. That's why I was grumpy all day.

Does the sentence above need past perfect anywhere?

Comment: Have you seen this site? http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html

Comment: @Jim Yes, I have! But I'm still confused even after visiting that site...

Answer (score 1):

In my view, both of your sentences are fine as they are written; no changes required.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect tense is used to show that a past even was still relevant at a later time.

> Mario had already arrived home when his mother walked in.

I could rephrase the previous sentence, and write "Mario arrived home; then, his mother walked in." and I would not use the past perfect tense.

In your sentence, the past perfect tense is not necessary.